# Static polymorphism with constant template

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I'd like to have a static polymorphism with the parent class having a template `std::array` size. This code works fine:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <size_t size>
class Message
{
  public:
    size_t GetSize() { return size; }
  private:
    std::array<uint8_t, size> data_{};
};

class Command : public Message<12>
{
  public:
    static const size_t kCmdSize{12};
  private:
};

class Reply : public Message<16>
{
  public:
    static const size_t kCmdSize{12};
  private:
};

int main()
{
    Command cmd{};
    Reply rpl{};
    cout << "Size: " << cmd.GetSize() << "|" << rpl.GetSize() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

But I'm not a huge fan of magic numbers.

Is there any way to use a constant declared in the child class as the parameter to the parent class? Something like that:

```
class Command : public Message<kCmdSize>
{
  public:
    static const size_t kCmdSize{12};
  private:
};
```

Using this directly attempts to use a variable from a class that doesn't exist yet.
Using C++14.

Comment: The standard approach is to use CRTP and a trait to propagate constants from the derived class to the base class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're fine with one extra layer of indirection, then you can use a "traits class" kind of solution:

```
#include <array>
#include <cstdint>

template <class T> struct MessageSize;

template <std::size_t size>
class Message {
  public:
    std::size_t GetSize() { return size; }

  private:
    std::array<std::uint8_t, size> data_{};
};

// Forward declare class for upcoming specialization.
class Command;

// Specialize message size for Command class.
template <> struct MessageSize<Command> {
  static constexpr std::size_t size = 12;
};

class Command : public Message<MessageSize<Command>::size> { };
```

Note that in my example the `Message` class itself does not use the `MessageSize` one. You could do that as well, and have `Command` inherit from `Message<Command>` instead, but that would make your inheritance tree look a whole lot different (i.e. classes with the same message length wouldn't have the same base class anymore).

You could of course add another layer of indirection in there, where you inherit from e.g. `MessageBase<Command>` which in turn inherits from `Message<MessageSize<Command>::size>`.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Sure they did. All classes with a message length of 12 would inherit from `Message<12>`. They wouldn't if they inherit from `Message<X>`, `Message<Y>`, ...

Comment: ah, I spotted the last paragraph, that's exactly what I thought of. This is kind of expanded and lazy case of CRTP, `Message<MessageSize<Command>::size>` is a mouthful though, and it's possible to hide that through specialization.

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, but then you get a dependent base, which will require using e.g. `this->` in the code. So I figured if OP could put up with explicitly inheriting using the `MessageSize` helper struct, then why not.

Comment: yeah, that's purely stylistical. but for 12 years I deal with project lead who hate to see such inheritance and just discard whole design if they see it. "I can't read that!"

Comment: True, but I've had projects where there was a lot of functionality in such dependent base classes and it gets annoying having to type `this->` hundreds of times :). But hey, if that's what the design needs...

Answer (score 1):

That's common problem and there is solution used widely, e.g. in implementations of  stream components of C++ library. The type definitions and constants related to concrete derived class became part of specialization for a trait class:

```
template <class T> 
struct CommandTrait;

template <class T> 
struct Message : public CommandTrait<T>
{
    constexpr size_t GetSize() { return this->kCmdSize; }  // or Message::kCmdSize, the same in this case

    std::array<std::uint8_t, Message::size> data_{};
};

template <size_t _Sz, size_t _CSc = 12 > 
struct MessageSize  {
  static constexpr std::size_t size = _Sz;
  static constexpr size_t kCmdSize{ _CSc };
};

template <> 
struct CommandTrait<struct Command> : MessageSize<12> {};

template <> 
struct CommandTrait<class Reply> : MessageSize<16> {};

class Command : public Message<Command>
{
};

class Reply : public Message<Reply>
{
};
```

Note that `this->` is important to suggest compiler that "kCmdSize" is a name depending on template's parameter. You need a template-dependant name (i.e. qualified for static use or using this-> for runtime). That tells compiler to expect that such name exist or will be existing in future, at time of instantiation. SHould not forget about possibility of using constexpr:

```
template <class T> 
struct Message : public CommandTrait<T>
{
    static constexpr size_t GetSize() { return Message::kCmdSize; }
    
    std::array<std::uint8_t, GetSize()> data_{};
};
```

Trait class may have a common base, but generally type erasure is not required where such structs are used.

Comment: Sorry, it won't work. I need the `size` to be able to declare `std::array` member variable.

Comment: @ilya1725 it would:  `std::array<std::uint8_t, Message::kCmdSize> data_{};` You need a template-dependant name  (i.e. qualified for static use or using this-> for runtime). That tells compiler to _expect_ that such name exist or will be existing in future, at time of instantiation

Comment: Yes, it will work for one child class. However, I had to update the question to better reflect the real problem.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this?
Is there a concern to pass the number from your main-instance instead of letting it hang open in the class impl.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

template <size_t size>
class Message
{
  public:
    size_t GetSize() { return size; }
  private:
    std::array<uint8_t, size> data_{};
};

template<size_t N>
class Command : public Message<N>
{
  public:
    static const size_t kCmdSize{N};
  private:
};

int main()
{
    Command<12> cmd{};
    cout << "Size: " << cmd.GetSize() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```